# How do I rotate an ImageView along with a Carousel

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, carousel

I am using the library [gtomato/carouselview](https://github.com/gtomato/carouselview) to create a carousel. The Carousel itself is done and working. But I have an ImageView next to the Carousel, and I'd like it to rotate/transform along with the Carousel; rather it rotates clockwise, counter-clockwise, or stops, it should follow the carousel.

The carousel looks like this:

[image]

As this rotates, an image should rotate along with it.

I tried the following with no luck. The image rotates clockwise by about 25 degrees and thats it. Even if I spin the carousel counter clockwise, the image rotates clockwise about 25 degrees. Also does the same when I "fling" the Carousel to rotate continuously.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carousel, container, false)

        carousel = v.findViewById(R.id.carousel)
        cylinder = v.findViewById(R.id.cylinder)

        carousel?.transformer = WheelViewTransformer()
        carousel?.adapter = CarouselAdapter()
        carousel?.isInfinite = true
        carousel?.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL

        carousel?.setOnScrollListener(object: CarouselView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollBegin(carouselView: CarouselView?) {

                super.onScrollBegin(carouselView)

                var scroll = carouselView?.currentOffset
                var rotPercentage = scroll!! / carouselView?.adapter!!.itemCount

                var r = cylinder?.rotation

                cylinder?.animate()!!.rotationBy(((2 * Math.PI -rotPercentage)).toFloat())
            }
        })

        return v
}
```

With iOS and iCarousel I can do the following and it works accordingly:

```swift
func carouselDidScroll(_ carousel: iCarousel) {
    let scroll: CGFloat = carousel.scrollOffset
    let rotPercentage = scroll / CGFloat(carousel.numberOfVisibleItems)
    _cylinderImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 2 * .pi * -rotPercentage) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following library below works better. Comes packed in with a way to add a background image to a carousel.

https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView